# How to disable window resizing in a flutter desktop app

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to disable screen resizing on a flutter desktop application but it doesn't seem to work. I also want to change the window title.

```
import 'package:desktop_window/desktop_window.dart';
    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await DesktopWindow.setMinWindowSize(const Size(1280, 720));
      await DesktopWindow.setMaxWindowSize(const Size(1280, 720));
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the window_manager package, with this package you can configure if the user should be able to resize the window or not. More info here:
https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager#setresizable